# Create a drill down and drill up in tableau with multiple one to many relationships

Tags: sql, join, charts, visualization, tableau-api

So I have 3 data sets, structured like this:

---

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| Last_Name | Salary | Tenure |
+-----------+--------+--------+  
| Hoinski   | 40000  | 2      |  
| Smith     | 90000  | 4      |
| Jones     | 120000 | 10     |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

---

```
+-----------+---------+-------+
| Last_Name | Status  | Count |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| Jones     | On Time | 4     |
| Jones     | Late    | 0     |
| Jones     | Missing | 1     |
| Hoinski   | On Time | 1     |
| Hoinski   | Late    | 2     |
| Hoinski   | Missing | 1     |
+-----------+---------+-------+
```

---

```
+-----------+---------+-------+
| Last_Name | Risk    | Count |
+-----------+---------+-------+  
| Jones     | High    | 2     |
| Jones     | Low     | 1     |
| Jones     | Medium  | 4     |
| Smith     | High    | 0     |
| Smith     | Low     | 1     |
| Smith     | Medium  | 3     |
| Hoinski   | High    | 2     |
| Hoinski   | Low     | 1     |
| Hoinski   | Medium  | 0     |
+-----------+---------+-------+
```

### What I want to accomplish

I want 2 pie charts for Status and Risk, and 1 scatter chart for Salary/Tenure. When I click on the scatter chart of Salary/Tenure, I want the pie charts to switch from totals to filtered by my selection. I got this to work.
The problem is when I click on a pie chart total, lets say "status=On Time" the other pie charts do not filter. In this example, only Jones and Hoinski have "on time" status, so the other pie chart of Risk should remove Smith but it doesn't.

The Pie charts only filter when I click on the scatter plot (and the data sums incorrectly).
[image]

This works great, but I need to remove the level of detail for the Last names.[image]

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic for SO since it's not a programming question.  Also, the reason for the sql and join tags is unclear.

Comment: the reason for sql and join tags is because I'm using two left joins between these 3 data sets, and I was wondering if there is room for error there. where would you suggest posting?

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com/about)."

Comment: There's a [pretty serious precedent](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tableau/info) for asking Tableau questions on SO. There's a very real programming element in the software. If Excel and comparable software is a viable topic on SO, so should Tableau.

Comment: @barker Your edit only hides the problem in your data and your dashboard. I suggest learning about [data normalization](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) before you try and analyze it. Otherwise all your results are going to be either wrong, or duct taped into the result you would expect from normalized data.

Comment: Thanks for the input Paul, could you suggest an alternative structure for these tables?

Comment: I would, but after reading the answers and comments below it looks like @AndrewLaPrise gave you some great advice to that end. If you want a more thorough answer than that, I'd ask a new question about normalized /recommended data for Tableau. Tableau doesn't like to eat disjoint summary data, [see here](http://www.theinformationlab.co.uk/2013/08/27/how-not-to-use-tableau/). Numbers 1, 3, and 5 in that link apply directly to what you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're just joining these three tables together. Here's what you end up with (I'll just show Jones):

```
+-----------+--------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+
| Last_Name | Salary | Tenure | Status  | CountS | Risk    | CountR |
+-----------+--------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+
| Jones     | 120000 | 10     | On Time | 4      | High    | 2      |
| Jones     | 120000 | 10     | Late    | 0      | High    | 2      |
| Jones     | 120000 | 10     | Missing | 1      | High    | 2      |
| Jones     | 120000 | 10     | On Time | 4      | Low     | 1      |
| Jones     | 120000 | 10     | Late    | 0      | Low     | 1      |
| Jones     | 120000 | 10     | Missing | 1      | Low     | 1      |
| Jones     | 120000 | 10     | On Time | 4      | Medium  | 4      |
| Jones     | 120000 | 10     | Late    | 0      | Medium  | 4      |
| Jones     | 120000 | 10     | Missing | 1      | Medium  | 4      |
+-----------+--------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+
```

The problem is that you're handing Tableau data that's already been aggregated instead of raw, unsummarized data. That makes the tables very difficult to join intuitively, and it makes Tableau's job of aggregating and filtering the data very challenging. You can see that joining these tables resulted in a lot of duplication.

That duplication is the source of your odd counts in the Status pie chart:

```
SELECT Status,
       SUM(CountS)
FROM [The joined tables]
WHERE last_name = 'Jones' -- Filtering by Jones
GROUP BY Status;
```

Yields:

```
+---------+--------+
| Status  | CountS |
+---------+--------+
| On Time | 12     |
| Late    | 0      |
| Missing | 3      |
+---------+--------+
```

All of your original numbers are multiplied by three because each row was duplicated twice.

Furthermore, let's filter by 'On Time' (click the pie slice) and see what happens to our Risk pie chart:

```
SELECT Risk,
       SUM(CountR)
FROM [The joined tables]
WHERE last_name = 'Jones' -- Filtering by Jones
AND Status = 'On Time' -- Filtering by On Time, by clicking the pie slice
GROUP BY Risk;
```

Yields:

```
+--------+--------+
| Risk   | CountR |
+--------+--------+
| High   | 2      |
| Low    | 1      |
| Medium | 4      |
+--------+--------+
```

That duplication has gotten us into trouble again.

If you can possibly get a raw, unsummarized version of this data, Tableau's going to handle that a LOT better, and you'll be able to do a LOT more with it. Otherwise, you're going to have to get creative (and frankly silly) with how you set up your filters and aggregations, and you'll find that the entire dashboard will end up being one ugly hack after another. Godspeed, buddy.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Andrew, exactly my problem. I can get the raw data... would my joins be the same?

Comment: I think the joins would still duplicate data without the aggregation I did. It still contains the 1 to many relationships.

Comment: Your joins would probably be essentially the same. I'm hoping you'll end up with a Status table with a row for every date and a field for `Status`. So a row might look like: `|Jones|18/09/2015|Late|` and `|Jones|19/09/2015|On Time|`. Then you can join that table to your Risk table on `last_name` and `Date`, and to your `employee_info` table on `last_name`. Then your pie charts can use `Number of Records` to determine the counts for each value of `Risk` instead of the pre-aggregated counts. Does your data look anything even remotely like that?

Comment: To clarify, if you have an employee_info table (it seems like you do) with salary and tenure, then there should be a single row per employee. Your Status and Risk tables probably have a single row per employee/date (or something like that). As long as you can uniquely identify every row in a comparable manner, you should be able to avoid the duplication problem and let Tableau handle the aggregations for you.

Comment: The problem is I don't have a unique identifier like time/date, which is why I aggregated the data by last_name.

Comment: This sounds like a new question to me. If you can show us the structure of your unaggregated data, maybe the SO community can band together to find a way to make it Tableau appropriate. Without knowing that, the answer I've provided is really the best anyone can possibly do for you. Date/times are by no means necessary, but you will need a way to join those Risk and Status tables together without any duplication if you hope to filter between them.

Comment: Agreed Andrew, couldn't I just look at the distinct last names and filter between the Risk and Status tables? For example, I click on Late status, i see repeating names, take the distinct values from there and look them up in the Risk table.

Comment: The problem is that your data (as it currently stands) shows no relationship between Risk and Status. If you click on a pie slice in the Risk pie chart, how do you expect the Status pie chart to be filtered (looking at your data, I have no idea)? Until your table has some field(s) showing that relationship, you'll just have to dirty-hack your way through everything. At this point, I would recommend NOT filtering between the pies, because it's currently meaningless. Based on the info we've been given, I believe this is the best answer we can possibly provide you.

Comment: If you'd like help in translating your current table structure into something that Tableau can handle/rock, I'd recommend asking a new question to that end. Folks (including me) will be crawling over each other to help you out with a problem like that! If you're not interested in that, you might be able to pull some of this off with clever aggregations. (You're already doing one - by `AVG`ing Tenure and Salary, you're "removing" the duplication.) But Risk and Status will never be able to meaningfully filter each other until you find a way to get that relationship into your tables. Good luck!

Comment: Andrew, I have it working perfectly without Pie charts, let me update with a screenshot. The problem is i need pie charts haha

Comment: 5 years of programming exp later, i can confirm this project was poorly set up with poor data sources, and a poor understanding of how a database should work.